# arXiv article says that code has been made available with the article, but I cannot find it

Tags: publications, arxiv, code

I'm reading an article on published a few years ago (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08130). It says in the article (p.4 at the bottom) that a Mathematica code was made available "as an auxiliary file associated with the preprint of the paper on arXiv" to reproduce the plots they show there, but I cannot seem to recover it on arXiv (there is no code available under the corresponding tab). Am I missing something? Is it common for this kind of code to be 'unshared' after a while? Is there still another way to find it besides directly contacting the author?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "Code" tab is a relatively new addition to arXiv I believe, and may not have been there yet when the preprint was submitted. However, you can click on "Other formats" under "Downloads" in the menu on the right, and download the source. The package contains a .nb file, which I suppose is the notebook you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! What app did you use to open the file? I seem to be having some trouble with the specific file type.

Comment: There is some info here: https://arxiv.org/help/unpack. On a Mac I used the tar command on the command line. I'm assuming there are tools for windows that can unpack .tar or .tar.gz files.

Comment: Under Windows, [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) would be a tool that can deal with .tar and .tar.gz.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: @ThomasBakx gentle reminder to accept the answer!

Comment: My apologies. Just did!